# Pygame - Remove / Kill Sprite after time period, without polling

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

Whenever I shoot the sprite I want to be able to remove it from the screen, but only after half a second has passed (or some other arbitrary time period). But I don't want to poll sleep to wait for that time period to end.

This is where I have come thus far:

```
# detect collision here - all good
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, badGuys, True, False)
for baddies in collisions.values():
    for bad in baddies:
        # do stuff
        baddiesToRemove.appendleft(bad)
        # since a collision occured set timer for that specific bad guy:
        startTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# now after 500 milliseconds have passed, sth like that:
milis = pygame.time.get_ticks() - startTime # result in milliseconds
if (milis > 500):
    badGuyToRemove = baddiesToRemove.pop()
    badGuyToRemove.kill() # i want to delete the sprite
```

I hope the code above was understandable. In short this won't work, unless I insert a `sleep()` in between to wait for some time and then delete the sprite. Of course this is not an option though, because the entire program would freeze for that time period. I have thought about maybe creating a thread to handle this timer? Could there a better option in pygame / python? Are there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every enemy sprite needs an own timer. If a bullet hits one of them, start the timer, check in the update method if the desired time has elapsed and then call `self.kill()`. (Press any key to start the timer of the enemy in this example.)

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 30))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.time = None

    def update(self):
        if self.time is not None:  # If the timer has been started...
            # and 500 ms have elapsed, kill the sprite.
            if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.time >= 500:
                self.kill()


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    enemy = Enemy((320, 240), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Start the timer by setting it to the current time.
                enemy.time = pg.time.get_ticks()

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like an animation!

I'm assuming you have some kind of time elapsed and/or frames elapsed counter. I'm away from an IDE at the moment and don't trust my on-the-fly pygame, but include something in your update function like the following:

```
def update(...):
  ...
  if (not alive) and wait_frames:
    wait_frames -= 1
  if (not alive) and (not wait_frames):
    # remove
  ...
```

Unless your update implementation is way different than how I've always used it, this should do the trick!